# Can I add a label below a Kendo UI radial gauge?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using KendoUI's radial gauge, and I want to add a label right between the 0 tick and the 300 tick. The initalization takes in an object that can have a label attribute but that configures the actual tick label whereas I want to add a new word centered in the middle such as "Pounds", "Miles", etc.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/radialgauge

[image: Image of gauge]

```
$("#gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
    pointer: {
        value: 37.4
    },
    scale: {
        startAngle: -30,
        endAngle: 210,

        minorUnit: 5,
        majorUnit: 25,

        min: 0,
        max: 100,
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle to try it with: http://jsfiddle.net/sThK3/104/

**UPDATE 1/25/2017:**
It is certainly possible, but even after reading their code I don't understand where the labels are coming from: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/radial-gauge/car-dashboard

Comment: Found the source of them labels, but I don't think you're going to like it, check the answer I just submitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it appears like your objective may not be feasible in the way you were hoping for.

After looking more closely at telerik's radial gauge example you linked I found an image resource used for this: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/dataviz/dashboards/car-dashboard.png [image: Image from Telerik's demo]

This image contains the labels you're referring to of {k/mh, x1000 RPM} and the images for the gas/temp on the right.

Floating a label over the gauge may be an alternative? Or building your own background-image that will contain the label you wanted. :(

That would be referred to in your CSS like follows:

```
#gauge-container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 614px;
            height: 324px;
            background: transparent url("../content/dataviz/dashboards/car-dashboard.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
        }
```

replacing ***../content/dataviz/dashboards/car-dashboard.png*** with your image that has the right label in it for you

I'm going to see if I can figure out how to float a label on this using your jsfiddle example.

**EDIT:** I got the goods for you now. Looks like by using the appropriate css you can float a label in the middle of your radial.

I accomplished this with the following:
JS:

```
 $("#gauge").append("<label>Test</label>");
```

CSS:

```
label {
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  float: center;
  }
```